# Any way to "force" a program with a hung OCX to close?

Tags: delphi

My Delphi 7 program uses an OCX to control some hardware.  I don't have any sample code so I am working through loading/using/unloading the control correctly.  Unfortunately, if I use the hardware and load the OCX, the main process will not completely quit when the application closes.
If I use the hardware, the OCX loads and everything works fine.  On the program closing, the OCX doesn't unload properly and my program doesn't close completely.  It leaves a small 24 meg footprint in memory that can only be seen in Task Manager.
If I rerun the program, everything works perfectly including the hardware.  If I use the hardware and then close the program, it leaves another 24 meg footprint.  Rinse and repeat.
Until I can get the OCX code working correctly, if there anyway I can "force" the unloading of the OCX control for now?  Or force the termination of the process?

Comment: Is this an "out of process" OXC that starts it's own process?

Comment: No, it executes within the main process.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to load it (including variable declarations)? I have a thought as to what the issue might be, but need the code to confirm it before wasting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

An OCX control is like a dll. It unloads one way or the other when the process is terminated. Windows reclaims all memory when a process is closed. Where do you see this memory? Only is this program called Activity Monitor? Could it be that that program is incorrect?

UPDATE:
After the new information you gave it is clear it is not about freeing memory, but about a process not being closed/terminated.

This could happen if some threads are still running. The 3rd party control might creat threads and has not terminated them yet. This might be a bug or maybe you have to call some finalize/uninitialize/dispose/close method on the 3rd party control?

Comment: Windows doesn't reclaim this memory.  :)
If I call the hardware and the OCX loads, then my program doesn't release all of its memory when it closes.  A small amount of memory, @ 24 megs, stays in memory.  
Sorry about using "Activity Monitor."  I meant "Task Manager."  I can open Task Manager and close the remaining program there.
I'm sorry if this sounds confusing.
I run the program, it works perfectly, and it closes.  No problem.
If I run the program and call the hardware, the ocx loads, but my program doesn't completely unload when I close the program.

Comment: So the process keeps running you mean? It does not actually terminate?

Comment: Exactly and thank you for the help.  I'll try to fit all of this in 600 chars.
If I execute the program but don't call the hardware, the process terminates.
If I run the program, call the hardware and then close the program, the memory size goes from @ 70 Megs to @ 24 Megs and the process doesn't terminate.  I can watch the memory decrease, in task manager, until it hits @ 24 megs.
If I run the program 10 times, call the hardware 10 times, and close the program 10 times, I'll have 10 running process with @ 24 Megs each.  What is weird is that the program and hardware still works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe it is best if you update your question with this info so others can understand your question better.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the program under the debugger, with breakpoints in all your unit finalization sections and in any OnClose methods you have.  If you have a form with no OnClose method, add one.  Then watch as the application terminates and see how far you get.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the Windows [`ExitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682658%28VS.85%29.aspx) function?